# SVG. How to fill inside of path with double ARC

Tags: html, svg

How do I properly fill the Arc of the following example? SVG doesn't seem to recognize the path as closed.

```
<body>
  <svg style="border:1px solid black;width:510px;height:250px">
    <path d="M 500 150 A 400 400 0 0 0 50 150 M 500 175 Z A 400 400 0 0 0 50 175 M 50 175 L 50 150 M 500 175 L 500 150 " fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" />
    </svg>
</body>
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lys7ucxq/1/

[Image of desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cf9R.jpg)

Comment: What's the output you're looking to get, compared to what you have now?

Comment: I've updated the question to include a picture of the desired output

Answer (score 4):

Each time you issue a moveTo M command, you are starting a new subpath. Thus your path consists of four subpaths (i.e. two arcs and two lines). You want a single subpath. For example...

```html
    <svg style="border:1px solid black;width:510px;height:250px">
        <path d="M 500 150 A 400 400 0 0 0 50 150 L 50 175 A 400 400 0 0 1 500 175 Z" fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" />
    </svg>
```

Comment: Great, that makes sense. Thanks!